# How can I edit a plain text file in Python?

Tags: python, file

I've been trying to create a python script that edits a file, but if the file is not already there, it has an error like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "openorcreatfile.py", line 56, in <module>
        fileHandle = (pathToFile, 'w')
        IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/The_File.txt'
```

It works fine if the file exists. I've also tried this:

```
    fileHandle = (pathToFile, 'w+')
```

But it comes up with the same error. Do I need to explicitly check if the file is there? If so, how do I create the file?

EDIT: Sorry, I realized the folder was missing. I'm an idiot.

Comment: I'm guessing (hoping) your line of code is actually `fileHandle = open(pathToFile, 'w')`.  The parent directories have to exist, but the file doesn't.  When opening with a write handle the file should be created if it did not already exist.

Comment: show us the code, not only the error. use copy&paste instead of retyping from memory (your second snipped cannot be right).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says "No such file or directory."

Since you're trying to create a file, that must not be what's missing. So you need to create the `/home/me/` directory.

See [os.makedirs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

Comment: This is the first answer to actually fit the exception shown, but I strongly doubt the OP is actually attempting to create `'/home/me/The_File.txt'`.  The OP still needs to show actual code.

Answer (score 4):

```
fo = open("myfile.txt", "wb")

fo.write('blah')

fo.close()
```

That's it, this will do the job.

Comment: you could add exception handling, in case the directory is not present.

Answer (score 3):

myfile = open('test.txt','w')

myfile.write("This is my first text file written in python\n")

myfile.close()

Comment: Turned out that it was a missing directory according to the question update.

Answer (score 2):

To check if the file is there you can do:

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile(pathToFile)
```

so you can handle it, only if it exists:

```
if os.path.isfile(pathToFile):
    fileHandle = (pathToFile, 'w')
else:
    pass #or other thing
```

There are several ways to create a file in python, but if you want to create a text file, take a look at [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), which I think is one of the easiest and most effective ways

Comment: This is entirely overkill.  `open(pathToFile, 'w')` will create the file unless the parent directory doesn't exist.  The OP needs to show actual code, not pseudo-code from memory, before anything can be done to properly diagnose the issue.

Comment: Actually it's a good suggestion to aid the op in troubleshooting the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("test")
```

Comment: While correct use of a context manager, this doesn't explain the error the user is encountering.